# Disabling mouse detection on child but remaining on parent

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe-animate

I add a movieclip dynamically.  At some point I draw the movieclip and place the bitmap within a MC inside the MC and add an Add filter to it.  Later I give Drag functionality to such parent movieclips.  I want the mouse to detect everything but the drawn bitmap.  I already have the movieclip that contains the bitmap set to mouseEnabled false & mouseChildren false.  But the bitmap is still detected by the mouse.  When I set the parent to mouseEnabled = false, the parent no longer drags, so that doesn't work.  When I set the parent to mouseChildren = false, nothing changes, the bitmap is still sensed.  How can I leave the drawn bitmap visible, but have the drag functionality ignore the MC-encased bitmap?

Comment: Just an idea. Set the bitmap's (or its container with **mouseChildren = false**) **name** to something specific. Like "*NoMouse*". Then in mouse event handlers ignore the event **if (e.target.name == "NoMouse")**, where **e** is the handler argument.

Comment: Are you saying you want the child Bitmap to stay locked at one same screen position even though its parent MC is being moved around by the mouse?

Comment: @VC.One The point is that a solid object can have the mouse interaction disabled, but its parent will still dispatch mouse events when the mouse interacts with the object.

Comment: @VC.One no, I want the whole package to be draggable, bitmap included. I just don't want the bitmap to be mouse-sensitive, because 90% of it is a giant, transparent box that goes way beyond what the eye perceives as the interactable object.

Comment: @Organis I like your thinking.  I think this won't work in my case because the bitmap is, unfortunately, at the top-most layer of the parent.  So it's always gonna be the target.  Another issue is that the bitmap blocks other instances of the same thing on layers below.  So I just need it to be ignored, if possible.  It works when I make it invisible, but then.. it's invisible and it needs to be visible so that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Organis I wonder if I could do the reverse of that though.. add the listener to something smaller inside the parent, which triggers the dragging of the parent?  Is that possible?

Comment: Then, you need to utilize this method: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getObjectsUnderPoint() Please take heed of **Stage** coordinate space (just like **hitTestPoint**) rather then local. so you get a list of children that are under (mouseX, mouseY) position and allow the event if there are objects other than bitmap and its container on the list, something like that.

Comment: Oh clever.  I've gotten it to check the objects, just hard to know what to do next.  With one object, I could just stop the dragging code if it's only hitting the bitmap.  But when there's two parents, it traces back [object Shape],[object Shape],[object Bitmap],[object Bitmap] etc.  I suppose I need it to select the last listed "shape" and have it start dragging the parent of that (if you're hitting a lower item, it's supposed to pop to the top and be dragged, like a jigsaw puzzle dragging behaviour).

Comment: I think i'll have to move the listener to the stage.. that's good, it will reduce the #.  I'll run a for loop in reverse, and break if it encounters a shape.. I think this could work..

Comment: How do I check if the array value is a shape?  I can loop through them but I can't figure out how to write an if statement that catches the shapes..

Comment: @ola.rogula **if (O is Shape)** where **O** if the given object. You use it generally **if (object_reference is ClassReference)**, it returns **true** if **object_reference** is the instance of the **ClassReference** or any its subclasses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193349/discussion-between-ola-rogula-and-organis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after a bit of discussion we figured out the following:

1. Playing with mouse directly wasn't the right way because of the display list hierarchy.
2. The answer was in the [DisplayObjectContainer.getObjectsUnderPoint(...)](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getObjectsUnderPoint()) method that returns an **Array** of given **DisplayObjectContainer**'s children and grandchildren that are directly under given point. With the use of **Mouse** coordinates as a point (keep in mind that you need to provide coordinates in **Stage** coordinate space, just like it is with **hitTestPoint**) you can get a list of display objects under the **Mouse** pointer and then handle the mouse events based on that information.

Also along the way there was a problem of figuring the classes of the collected objects, the solution is pretty simple.

```
// We are in the root here.
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);

function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var aPoint:Point = localToGlobal(new Point(mouseX, mouseY));
    var aList:Array = getObjectsUnderPoint(aPoint);

    // Lets browse through all the results.
    for each (var aChild:DisplayObject in aList)
    {
        // How to find if an object is an instance of certain Class.
        if (aChild is Shape)
        {
            trace("A Shape was found under a name of", aChild.name, "!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @VC.One *bows humbly*

Comment: I got this to fully work, thanks! If it helps anyone, I had to add a counter because it also catches the background as a shape, so, to only count clicks with 2+ shapes. And then I had to add a long if statement to try to deduce the path of the target, in order to know which parent it came from, to know which parent to start dragging (the MCs have a lot of nesting in this case so lots of possible targets and paths)

Comment: @ola.rogula Glad it helped : )